# Changing a VARCHAR with MySQL PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db->query("UPDATE `".MLS_PREFIX."users` SET `logo` = $icon WHERE `userid` = $id");
```

The query thing works fine, but logo doesn't change. It is a VARCHAR and I made sure $icon is a string. It does not change, but I have the same query somewhere else just changing a INT and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$db->query("UPDATE `".MLS_PREFIX."users` SET `logo` = '$icon' WHERE `userid` = $id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
$db->query("UPDATE `".MLS_PREFIX."users` SET `logo` = {'$icon'} WHERE `userid` = {'$id'}");
```